# SQL: Count references to item in same table

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL table:

```
id     int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name   varchar(200),
parent int(11),
```

This stores some structured information in a tree:

- "id" is the primary (uniq) key of the entries
- "name" is some string
- "parent" is the "id" of the parent entry (0: root element)

A sample table could be:

```
id name              parent
--+-----------------+----------------
1  root_a             0
2  root_b             0
3  sub_b1             2
4  sub_sub_b1_1       3
5  sub_sub_b1_2       3
```

This could be a directory with folder ("root_*"), sub-folder ("sub_*"), sub-sub-folder ("sub_sub_*"), ...

Now I would like to have a SQL query, that returns for each entry how many child entries there are:

```
SELECT id,name,count(....) as child_count FROM table WHERE ...
```

For the example table this query shall return:

```
 id  name         child_count
 --+--------------+---------
 1  root_a         0
 2  root_b         1
 3  sub_b1         2
 4  sub_sub_b1_1   0
 5  sub_sub_b1_2   0
```

How to perform such a count inside the same table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about a correlated subquery?

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.parent = t.id
       ) as child_count
from t;
```

Comment: Hey, this correlated subquery works fine, THANKS!

Comment: Is the are simple solution to get ALL childs (sub, sub-sub, ...) of an entry?
This correlated subquery gets the direct children, but not the children of the children (and children of children of children, ...).
In my example for "root_b" this could will be 1+2=3.

Comment: @devtry . . . That would be a different question and should be asked as a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and database tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
with qry1 as (
    select      parent, 
                count(*) as child_count 
    from        table 
    group by    parent
)
select      table.id, 
            table.name, 
            isnull(qry1.child_count, 0) as child_count
from        table 
left join   qry1 
on          table.id = qry1.parent
order by    table.id
```

**Note**: Left Join. Inner join would exclude rows with no children.