# Left join returning null instead of 0

Tags: database, postgresql

So I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Ex Table:
id, Name, To
1,  A,    2
2,  B,    0
3,  C,    2
4,  D,    0
5,  E,    1

Expected results:
id, Name, To, Count
1,  A,    2,  1
2,  B,    0,  2
3,  C,    2,  0
4,  D,    0,  0
5,  E,    1,  0
```

Here I'm trying to get a count of rows being referenced each time. For example row with id 1 is referenced once in a row with id 5, similarly row with id 2 is referenced twice in rows with id 1 and id 3.

This is what I have tried:

```
select *
from sample
left join(
          select "to", count(*)
          from sample
          group by "to") j on j."to" = sample."id"
```

and this is what I'm getting:

```
Results:

id, Name, To, Count
1,  A,    1,  1
2,  B,    2,  2
3,  C,    null,null
4,  D,    null,null
5,  E,    null,null
```

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Comment: What you get is the expected result. You're matching `to` and `id`. Why would ID 3 match 2 ?

Comment: Well id 3 won't match id 2, the row with id 3 has a reference(column: To) to the row with id 2

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. I ended up using a correlated query.

```
select *,
       (select count(to)
        from sample s
        where s.to = sample.id
       ) as ct
from sample;
```

Thanks to: [Gordon Linoff's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66943803/20026121)